# Visual C# Express 2008 Form Designer AutoScroll

Tags: visual-studio, forms, designer

This may not be the kind of question one should ask on StackOverflow, but here's a frustration that I've been trying to find a work-around for.

When using the form designer, suppose the entire form does not fit in the space allotted to the form designer, and I have a control say, down near the bottom of the form.

If I try to re-size that control, or move it using the mouse, the work area will auto-scroll to the top of the work area. This essentially pulls my control to the top of the screen. It isn't possible to scroll with the scroll wheel while "holding" a control, and even ScrollLock does nothing for me.

Is there any way to just turn the auto-scrolling off? That way I can at least work on my form without guessing numbers to type into the properties window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just turn off autoscroll for the form?

I think it's off by default.

Form.AutoScroll = False

Comment: I mean in the form designer, not the actual form.